# Clojure - Is it possible to increment a variable within a doseq statement?

Tags: clojure

I am trying to iterate over a list of files in a given directory, and add an incrementing variable i = {1,2,3.....} to their names.

Here is the code I have for iterating through the files and changing each file's name:

```
(defn addCounterToExtIn [d]
  (def i 0)
  (doseq [f (.listFiles (file d)) ] ; make a sequence of all files in d
    (if (and (not (.isDirectory f)) ; if file is not a directry and
             (= '(\. \i \n) (take-last 3 (.getName f))) ) ; if it ends with .in
      (fs/rename f (str d '/ i (.getName f)))))) ; add i to start of its name
```

I don't know how can I increment `i` as `doseq` iterates through each file. Alternatively, is there a better loop to use to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Why are you making the scope of the variable extend beyond the operation it's used for?

Comment: `def` creates a top level `var` which as Charles Duffy points out is a top level value that exists beyond the run of your function, and more importantly it is usually the wrong thing to make if you want mutation. Also, the idiomatic thing in clojure is to eliminate the direct usage of mutation entirely (as shown in his answer below).

Comment: You may find this piece of code helpful: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6981825/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use [`file-seq`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/file-seq) and [`map-indexed`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/map-indexed):

```
(require '[clojure.java.io :as io])

(dorun
  (->>
    (file-seq (io/file "/home/eduard/Downloads"))
    (filter #(re-find #".+\.pdf$" (.getName %)))
    (map-indexed (fn [i v] [i v]))))
```

Change function in `map-indexed` to rename and you're done.
The sample output for pdf files:

```
([0 #<File /home/eduard/Downloads/some.pdf>] ...)
```

Comment: Thank you -- I was actually looking for map-indexed to revise my own answer when you found this. :)

Comment: Please note that file-seq is recursive and will also return files in sub-directories.

Comment: Is there a way to have the index start with a value other than 0?

Comment: @YechielLabunskiy you can `(inc i)` inside function for map-indexed. I think you already got this answer :)

Answer (score 3):

This is the first approach off the top of my head. It's not ideal, but certainly more idiomatic than what the question proposes.

```
(def rename-one-file! [file counter]
  (if (and (not (.isDirectory file))
           (= ".in" (str (take-last 3 (.getName file)))))
      (fs/rename file (file (parent dir)
                            (str counter (.getName file)))))


(defn iterate-files-with-counter [fn dir]
  (loop [counter 0
         remaining-files (.listFiles (file dir))]
    (let [current-file (first remaining-files)]
      (fn file counter)
      (recur (+ counter 1) (rest remaining-files))))

(def add-counter-to-ext-in-dir
  (partial iterate-files-with-counter rename-one-file!))
```

Note that the work of actually performing the rename was split off from the work of iterating over the files. Having a large number of small functions is better than than a small number of large functions in general, and making those functions reusable / independent unless you choose to use them together is even better than that.

Comment: Note that this was all written off-the-cuff without testing, so it's sure to not be perfect -- but the goal is to show idiom / good practice.

Comment: In a case like this, is it actually crucial to follow idiom, or I could as well have used mutation, but you just wanted to show me the idiomatic way of doing the same?

Comment: @YechielLabunskiy, using vars for mutation leads to real-world bugs and performance issues. It's not always critical to get your idioms right, but the initial code had real-world bugs (for instance, think what would have happened if it had been called from two threads at once).