# Iterate SQL result in clojure and update the values

Tags: java, loops, clojure, functional-programming

I am learning clojure and am currently stuck at something that would've take a few minutes to solve in an object oriented language. I'm trying to wrap my head around something (possibly trivial?) that I am having trouble understanding. So here goes.

What I've got is a variable that contains the results from a SQL query that I'm making. It contains a list of email addresses that are returned from the DB. So effectively the below def contains a lazy sequence of email addresses.

```
(def sql-results (... sql call ...)
```

What I'm trying to do is iterate through sql-results one by one, and change one of the keys (email) in all the rows of the response, from it's current form which is this:

```
[ 
  { email: abc@gmail.com, somekey: somevalue }, 
  { email: xyz@someone.com, somekey: somevalue }, 
  { email: lmn@yahoo.com, somekey: somevalue } 
]
```

to something like this below:

```
[ 
  { emailAddress: abc@gmail.com, somekey: somevalue },   
  { emailAddress: xyz@someone.com, somekey: somevalue },   
  { emailAddress: lmn@yahoo.com, somekey: somevalue } 
]
```

Since I come from Java background, the way I'd do this in Java is pass the sql result object to a method that will iterate through all the rows in the object, change the key for each row from 'email' to 'emailAddress'. The method will return that object with all rows having the modified key value. The calling method will simply assign this changed object to some other variable.

When I try to change the value from 'email' to 'emailAddress' by passing the current row to that function, it returns the formatted value correctly. But at the end of the iteration the new values does not seem to hold.

I understand mutability being the corner stone of clojure. With that and bindings in mind, how do I get around this problem? Should I use something other than doseq? 'for' perhaps? Any ideas or suggestions would do.

This is the code I have currently:

```
(defn iterate-results [sql-results]
        (doseq [row sql-results]
          (def new-row-value (format-email-key row)) 
          (println "after change ---> " new-row-value) ;This correctly shows the new value of ‘emailAddress’
          [new-row-value] ; I'm not sure how this works
        )

 (println sql-results); This still has pre-change values. I want the new values here.
 )
```

I think this is the closest problem I could find on SO in the last 2 days to the one I'm having: [Clojure - Is it possible to increment a variable within a doseq statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21962093/clojure-is-it-possible-to-increment-a-variable-within-a-doseq-statement)

Comment: Please follow Alan's suggestion and read Clojure for the Brave and True or other introductory book about fp or Clojure. You basically tried to replicate Java's imperative nature with Clojure code, this kind of approach will lead you to a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(defn normalize-email
  "Change :email key to :email-address"
  [item]
  (let [email-val (:email item)
        item-without-email (dissoc item :email)
        result (assoc item-without-email :email-address email-val)]
    result))

(def data-orig
  [{:email "abc@gmail.com", :somekey :somevalue-1},
   {:email "xyz@:someone.com", :somekey :somevalue-2},
   {:email "lmn@yahoo.com", :somekey :somevalue-3}])

(mapv normalize-email data-orig) => 

  [{:somekey :somevalue-1, :email-address "abc@gmail.com"}
   {:somekey :somevalue-2, :email-address "xyz@:someone.com"}
   {:somekey :somevalue-3, :email-address "lmn@yahoo.com"}]
```

You may wish to get started by looking online at [Clojure For the Brave and True](http://www.braveclojure.com/clojure-for-the-brave-and-true/) and numerous other good Clojure books.  Also

- [The Clojure Cheatsheet](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html)
- [ClojureDocs.org](http://ClojureDocs.org)

Comment: Thanks, Alan. This is exactly what I was looking for. +1 for citing the helpful tutorials. I'll go through them.

Answer (score 1):

basically the same as @Alan Thompson's variant, but a bit more concise:

```
user> (map (fn [{:keys [email] :as result}]
             (-> result
                 (dissoc :email)
                 (assoc :email-address email)))
           sql-results)

;;({:somekey "somevalue", :email-address "abc@gmail.com"} 
;; {:somekey "somevalue", :email-address "xyz@someone.com"} 
;; {:somekey "somevalue", :email-address "lmn@yahoo.com"})
```

or just using `rename-keys` function from `clojure.set` package:

```
user> (map #(clojure.set/rename-keys % {:email :email-address})
           sql-results)
```